# Call function from Sessionbean and populate table with angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, button

I have two problems:

1. I have no idea how to call a java class function in a html page using angularJS.
2. I need my button to be disabled after it is used.

My address is this: http://localhost:8080/CreditCardWEB/rest/cc/init

I have this in my class:

CardBean.java

```
@GET
@Path("/init")
public void init() {
    Student s = new Student(1, "Pera", "Peric");
    em.persist(s);
    s = new Student(2, "Pera2", "Peric2");
    em.persist(s);
    s = new Student(3, "Pera3", "Peric3");
    em.persist(s);
}
```

In my indexStud.html page, I have a button:

```
<button ng-click="initStud()">Init Student</button>
```

In my controllers.js I have the problem, but I have no idea how to do it:

```
$scope.initStud = function() {
    //call the function from Cardbean.java 
    //disable the button after he is used
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the answer to question number 1....and here is it

```
        $scope.initStud = function() {
            $http.post('http://localhost:8080/CreditCardWEB/rest/cc/init').success(
            function(data) {
            });
}
```

thats needed in the controllers.js file
and the @GET in the 1st line in the Cardbean.java file has to be changed to @POST